# How to use returned JSON objects to populate table as opposed to populating your own Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my code, obviously it isn't going to Run because I have external sources that I am pulling from. My main issue is that I can't get the listItemInfo from onQuerySucc to display in the table in the buildTable function. Does anyone know how I can do that? I have it working when I populate the array itself, but I don't want to do it that way.

After onQuerySucc(data) runs, it displays the list item information it pulled like so:

**Name**: Deacon Landen – **Age**: 34 - **Position**: Jr. Developer - **Office**: Charleston- **Education**: UVA - **Degree**: Law

How can I get that to populate to my table so I do not have to manually populate the employees array?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function() {
    getListData();
  });
});

function getListData() {
  var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";

  $.ajax({
    url: fullUrl,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: onQuerySucc,
    error: onQueryFlop
  });
}

function onQuerySucc(data) {
  var listItemInfo = "";
  $.each(data.d.results, function(key, value) {
    listItemInfo += '<b>Name:</b> ' + value.Title + ' – <b>Age:</b> ' + value.Age + ' - <b>Position:</b> ' + value.Position + ' - <b>Office:</b> ' + value.Office + ' - <b>Education:</b> ' + value.Education + ' - <b>Degree:</b> ' + value.Degree + '<br/>';
  });
  $("#divResults").html(listItemInfo);
  alert('Successfully pulled list items');
}

function onQueryFlop() {
  alert('Error! Could not read list items');
}

$(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit1").on("click", function() {
    buildTable();
  });
});

function buildTable(data) {
  var employees = new Array();
  employees.push(["Name", "Age", "Position", "Office", "Education", "Degree"]);
  employees.push(["Deacon Landen", "34", "Jr. Developer", "Charleston", "UVA", "Law"]);
  employees.push(["Leon Brooklyn", "19", "Intern", "Charleston", "Richmond", "Civil Engineering"]);
  employees.push(["Dederick Dell", "26", "Sr. Developer", "Richmond", "Georgia", "Electrical Engineering"]);
  employees.push(["Jojo Vincent ", "46", "Chief Financial Officer", "Richmond", "Ole Miss", "Business Admin"]);
  employees.push(["Nelly Jerred", "41", "Program Analyst", "Charleston", "Columbia", "Computer Science"]);
  employees.push(["Brendan Diaz", "46", "Chief Operating Officer", "Stafford", "Alabama", "MIS"]);

  //Create a HTML Table element.
  var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
  table.border = "1";

  //Get the count of columns.
  var columnCount = employees[0].length;

  //Add the header row.
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
    headerCell.innerHTML = employees[0][i];
    row.appendChild(headerCell);
  }

  //Add the data rows.
  for (var i = 1; i < employees.length; i++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
      cell.innerHTML = employees[i][j];
    }
  }

  var tblResults = document.getElementById("tblResults");
  tblResults.innerHTML = "";
  tblResults.appendChild(table);
  alert('Successfully displayed items in Table Format');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" data-dpmaxz-eid="45" value="Click Here for EmployeeInfo" />&#160;<br/></div>
<div id="divResults">​​​<br/></div>
<br>
<div>
  <input id="btnSubmit1" type="button" data-dpmaxz-eid="45" value="Click Here for Table View" />&#160;<br/></div>
<div id="tblResults">​​​<br/></div>

<script src="/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<br>
```

Comment: Use `dataType: 'json'` so that the response will be parsed automatically.

Comment: There's no point in sending `content-type` with a `GET` request, since it doesn't have any content.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, going off of that though, how would I still populate the table with the parsed json return. This is for a work project so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildTables` should get `employees` from its parameter, not hard-code the array. Then call `buildTables()` from the `success:` option of `getListData()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function() {
    getListData();
  });
});

function getListData() {
  var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";

  $.ajax({
    url: fullUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: buildTable,
    error: onQueryFlop
  });
}

function onQueryFlop() {
  alert('Error! Could not read list items');
}

function buildTable(employees) {
  var headings = ["Name", "Age", "Position", "Office", "Education", "Degree"];

  //Create a HTML Table element.
  var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
  table.border = "1";

  //Add the header row.
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  headings.forEach(h => {
    var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
    headerCell.innerHTML = h;
    row.appendChild(headerCell);
  });

  //Add the data rows.
  for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    headings.forEach(h => {
      var headerCell = document.createElement("TD");
      headerCell.innerHTML = employees[i][h];
      row.appendChild(headerCell);
    });
  }

  var tblResults = document.getElementById("tblResults");
  tblResults.innerHTML = "";
  tblResults.appendChild(table);
  alert('Successfully displayed items in Table Format');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" data-dpmaxz-eid="45" value="Click Here for EmployeeInfo" />&#160;<br/></div>
<div id="divResults">​​​<br/></div>
<br>
<div>
  <input id="btnSubmit1" type="button" data-dpmaxz-eid="45" value="Click Here for Table View" />&#160;<br/></div>
<div id="tblResults">​​​<br/></div>

<script src="/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<br>
```

Comment: when I execute it in a Script Editor webpart, it only populates the headers and not actually the table rows/data

Comment: Sorry, I was processing the returned data as a 2-dimensional array, rather than an array of objects.

Comment: All good, would you mind showing where that error is so I can fix accordingly. You are awesome.

Comment: It doesn't show that you have edited anything more recently,

Comment: Ah, I can see your most recent edit now, but it still is not working. Nothing is displayed.

Comment: Do you see the data in `console.log(employees);`?

Comment: I do not see the data in console.log(employees). Your first edit atleast displayed the table headers with no data, but now nothing displays at all and when the button is clocked, there is no alert nor any action

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:8
    at dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:8
    at dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:8

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Url' of undefined
    at Object.success (suiteux.shell.crossdomainproxyiframe.774e011e6cd24ffb99a5.js:114)
    at u (suiteux.shell.crossdomainproxyiframe.774e011e6cd24ffb99a5.js:93)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (suiteux.shell.crossdomainproxyiframe.774e011e6cd24ffb99a5.js:93)
    at C (suiteux.shell.crossdomainproxyiframe.774e011e6cd24ffb99a5.js:93)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (suiteux.shell.crossdomainproxyiframe.774e011e6cd24ffb99a5.js:93)

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) 
r

Comment: it is also deploying the "headers" into the table body

Comment: None of those errors seem to be related to this code, but they could be interfering with it.

Comment: If you're using `dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js` you probably also have to load the Bootstrap library.

Comment: I have bootstrap in there, but I am not using it. I literally just need the items to populate the simplest html table.

Comment: You need to figure out what's causing those errors. Maybe a browser extension? I tried googling `suiteux.shell.crossdomainproxyiframe`, but didn't understand what I found.